# Search for place in Google map and get back longitude and latitude

Tags: android, google-maps

I need the user to search for the name of a place in a textview, and the Mapview would put a marker/pin on the nearest matching result in the Map. If the user confirms, the latitude and longitude would be returned. I am not sure how to go about this and if this is even possible. Please point me to the right direction. I have searched through lots of forums but could not get any ideas. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using [GeoCoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) class. If you know the address of a location but want to know its latitude and longitude, you can do so via **reverse-Geocoding**.

As far as adding map pins based on the search result you need to use ItemizedOverly. Please follow this tutorial, its very detailed and also offer what you are looking for. 
[Using Google Maps in Android](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android), see the section **Geocoding and Reverse Geocoding**

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helped. I am looking into it. Is it possible for me to search for the exact address and then put a marker? Here is an example - you are in a new city, say Baltimore, and just ate at a pizza place "Joey's pizza". Is it possible for the user to search "Joey's Pizza, Main street, Baltimore" and get the marker on the map? I apologize if my question is a bit confusing.

Comment: Nevermind, reading the article that you mentioned, I found that you can get address of places by geoCoder.getFromLocationName(). Thanks once again for your help!